# size_t(-1) and int(-1) under 64-bit system

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I wrote a test code for verifying some issues of 64-bit porting. But I was confused with the following cases:

```
size_t size_neg_one = (size_t(-1));
int int_neg_one = -1;
printf("size_neg_one = %#zu, int_neg_one = %#x\n", size_neg_one, int_neg_one);
```

The output result is:

```
size_neg_one = 0xffffffffffffffff
int_neg_one  = 0xffffffff
```

Obviously, `size_neg_one` shouldn't equal to `int_neg_one`. But I tried `if(size_neg_one == int_neg_one)` and got `TRUE`. It doesn't match my expectation.

Could someone explain this condition for me? Thanks in advance.

My DEV environment: **64-bit Xubuntu 13.04** with **gcc-4.6.3**.

Comment: You can't compare two separate arithmetic types. One of them gets converted into the other.

Comment: size_t(-1) I think is undefined behavior.

Comment: @40two: It's fine, wrap-around is guaranteed.

Comment: @40two: No, it's defined to be reduced by modular arithmetic to give the maximum value of `size_t`.

Comment: `gcc` will give a syntax error for `(size_t(-1))`. This is illegal in C.

Comment: @LeeDuhem: The question is about C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That is because I removed the original `C` tag.

Comment: I think that's integral promotion what's going on there before the comparison. sign is preserved, so comparison yields true.

Comment: @Hayri Uğur Koltuk: Not sure what you mean by "sign is preserved", considering that this is an *unsigned* comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So `int` (32Bit 2-s complement) is converted to `size_t` (64Bit unsigned), by adding 2^64 to -1.

Just about every compiler will warn about such a comparison though.

Comment: The first statement isn't quite true (at least not formally): the smaller one gets converted directly to the type of the larger; there's no widening, then reinterpreting.  (In practice, I can't think of a case where it would make a difference.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Rewritten with standard quote giving the explicit rules.

Answer (score 1):

Most binary operators, including `==`, work on two values with the same type. If the two types are different, then one or both is *promoted* so that they match.

The rules are quite complicated but, in this case, `int_neg_one` is promoted to `size_t`. This uses exactly the same conversion as the cast used to give `size_neg_one` its value, and so the  comparison compares two equal values and yields `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare size_t to INT one of them gets implicitly converted to the other.

Comment: Care to say which one, or let him guess? (`unsigned` is always preferrred)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `printf` is broken. It produces undefined behavior. You used `%x` format specifier with an `int` argument. `%x` requires `unsigned int` argument, not an `int` argument. While this combination might still be legal for a non-negative `int` value, it is not defined for negative values. In other words, the `int_neg_one = 0xffffffff` output you observe has no particular meaning in the language. The output is rather obviously meaningless, since the positive value `0xffffffff` is out of range of type `int` on your platform.

Secondly, as for `size_neg_one == int_neg_one` equality, as other have already explained, according to the rules of the language the comparison is performed in the domain of unsigned type `size_t`, meaning that your comparison is actually interpreted as

```
size_neg_one == size_t(int_neg_one)
```

The right-hand size produces the same value as your `size_t(-1)`, which is why the equality holds.

Comment: The problem with `printf` is more complex than that.  There are special rules which allow substituting a signed integral type for the unsigned and vice versa.  (On the other hand, they only apply when the actual value is representable in both, which isn't the case here.)

Comment: @James Kanze: This is basically what I meant by my "...this combination might still be legal for a non-negative `int` value...", since all non-negative values of signed type are supposed to be representable in the corresponding unsigned type. And for such mutually-representable values the types are supposed to be interchangeable in function argument contexts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare values, both operands must have the same
type, which is determined by a somewhat complex set of rules; in
particular, in this case, in the unlikely case that `size_t` is
smaller than `int`, the rules are different than if it is the
same size or larger.  Assuming the usual case, however, where
`size_t` is larger than or the same size as `int`, the `int`
will be converted into `size_t`.  Since `size_t` is guaranteed
to be an unsigned integral type, if the integral type is
negative, the results of the conversion are defined as the
mathematical correct results of
`std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1 + int_value`.  (The
mathematically correct results, because within C++, the results
of `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1` are guaranteed to be
0.)